# Objective-C instance into C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, instance, objective-c++, pimpl-idiom

How I can instantiate a Objective-c class into CPP class?

for example my CPP class:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
private:
    MyObjcClass* myObjcClass; //it does not work
}
```

how I can do this?

note I using .m for Objective-C and .cpp for C++.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Despite you not wanting it, you **are going to need** to use the `.mm` extension if you want this.

Comment: @H2CO3 You have reason, sorry. I update the question.

Comment: so why don't you just rename the files to `.mm`?

Comment: @H2CO3 because that CPP class is used mutually for IOS and Android, because this I need a cpp class, that Obj-c object received an ifdef in late.

Comment: in this case, you can pass `-x obj-c++` as a compiler flag to clang.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks but declaring as follow id myObjcClass; instead MyObjcClass* myObjcClass; works fine without compiler flags :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

- compile as Objective-C++
- or declare it as `id`.

If you use `id`, you should introduce the type in your definitions, e.g.:

```
// Foo.mm
Foo::~Foo() {
  MyObjcClass * a = this->myObjcClass;
  [a release];
}
```

In general, you should preserve the type (`MyObjcClass`) and *avoid* using `id`, but declaring the variable as `id` is compatible with C and C++, so you can use `id` to avoid compiling everything that includes Foo.hpp as ObjC++.

Comment: @ademar111190 perhaps you are looking for: `Foo::Foo() : myObjcClass([MyObjcClass new]) {}`? if you chose `id`, only `Foo` would need to change to compile as ObjC++, but everything that saw Foo would need just C++.

Comment: perfect!!! dataDownload = [DataDownload new]; work too, but a very thank you justin :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.  The sane way is to use Objective-C++.  You can either do this with files that have a `.mm` extension or you can change your build settings.  The default is to compile based on the file extension, but you can force it use Objective-C++ on a `.cpp` or `.m` file.

The crazy way is to use the raw Objective-C interface in objc.h.

Comment: Both true, but there's a third way, which is to just use `id` in all the pure C++ code, and move the code that must be ObjC (or ObjC++) into separate files, as justin suggests.